# jquery toggle switch programmatcally on off

Tags: jquery-ui, toggleswitch

Hi Im using jquery ui toggleswitch 
[toggleswitch.js](https://github.com/jamiebicknell/Toggle-Switch/blob/master/example.html) I can get on off value but

how can i set on /off value programmatically in javascript or jquery

i'm using this code on change but i want to set it on document ready

```
  $('.toggleEmailStatus').toggleSwitch().change(function (ev) {
        alert(ev);
        try {

            console.log("value= " + $(this).val());

        } catch (e) {
            alert(e);
        }     
 });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can programmatically turn it on or off by [triggering](http://api.jquery.com/trigger) a click on the respective checkbox:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $('.toggleswitch').toggleSwitch();
  $("#opt2").trigger("click"); // turn it on
});
```

```html
<link href="https://raw.githack.com/jamiebicknell/Toggle-Switch/master/toggleswitch.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://raw.githack.com/jamiebicknell/Toggle-Switch/master/jquery.toggleswitch.js'></script>
<label for='opt1'>Option 1</label>
<input type='checkbox' name='opt1' id='opt1' value='1' class='toggleswitch' checked='checked' />

<!-- Switch is OFF -->
<label for='opt2'>Option 2 (off by default)</label>
<input type='checkbox' name='opt2' id='opt2' value='1' class='toggleswitch' />
```

Comment: The sample code does not work. Is there an updated version of this code?

Comment: @YacoZaragoza it seems to work for me. The second toggle is enabled programatically by the `$("#opt2").trigger("click");` line...